# Google maps JS API referer URL

Tags: javascript, api, mobile, maps

Does google maps JS API (v3) support any referer URLs other than http:// or https:// protocol?

I'm building a series of native mobile application (ios, android and windows), but wanted to integrate google maps js api, because most of the UIs in my application are developed with html5/js. And yes, we are bundling all our js/html assets with the native application. Therefore, the google maps js library will get a referer URL like file:///var/mobile/Container/...., but seems this kind of referer URL is not supported by google.

an alternative solution is to setup a mini server on the device to host all js/html assets, and then register http://localhost as one of the referer url. But I really want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google for Work Support Portal where you can authorize URLs they list under examples as well a file path (file:/C:/Documents/MapsDemo/main.html), but they write besides that you need to open a case for adding it. Adding file paths yourself doesn't work.